# Use if with radio button and text filed both?

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans, radio-button, textfield

I have panel with absolute layout, a label where an image is shown and three radio buttons, brown, blue and red.

When I enter a name of car like Audi A4 in the text field, then a default image is shown and the brown radio button is selected.But when I select blue and red radio button then a image is displayed of A4 blue or A4 red but it doesn't respond.

```
private void fmod1FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    String mod;
    mod=fmod1.getText();

    if(mod.equals("A4")) {
    rbrown.setSelected(true);   
    imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Photo\\a4brown.jpg"));
    fcolour1.setText("Brown");

    if (rblue.isSelected()==true) {
    imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Photo\\a4blue.jpg"));
    fcolour1.setText("Blue");
  } 
    else if (rred.isSelected() == true) {
    imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Photo\\a4red.jpg"));
    fcolour1.setText("red");
  }
}
 else if(mod.equals("R8"))
    {

        rbrown.setSelected(true);
        imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Photo\\r8brown.jpg"));
      fcolour1.setText("Brown");

    if (rblue.isSelected()==true)
           {
                imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Photo\\r8blue.jpg"));
  fcolour1.setText("Blue");
           }
           else if(rred.isSelected()==true)
           {
                imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Photo\\r8red.jpg"));
  fcolour1.setText("red");
           }
           }
```

and so on for R8,RS5.

I need a solution without swing.

Comment: I understood only one thing in this question: Nothing.

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? The code above doesn't say much about listeners and such. Something that is important to event handling.

Comment: Also you need to explain what exactly you wish to occur.

Comment: Two points: * Why without Swing? * Your urgency is not our urgency, and no one is going to ask to "please help in the next month or so", so it's better to refrain from using "as soon as possible" in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown us, does nothing to capture the event of the user selecting a different radio button. And since you're selecting the radio button for brown, that one is shown.

You need to add an event handler for the radio buttons.

```
// This should be the code that responds to entering a different model
rbrown.setSelected(true);   


// Something like this should be the code that responds to 
// a radio button being selected
mod = fmod1.getText();

if(mod.equals("A4"))
{
    if (rbrown.isSelected())
    {
        imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Photo\\a4brown.jpg"));
        fcolour1.setText("Brown");
    }
    else if (rblue.isSelected())
    {
        imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Photo\\a4blue.jpg"));
        fcolour1.setText("Blue");
    }
    else if(rred.isSelected())
    {
        imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Photo\\a4red.jpg"));
        fcolour1.setText("red");
    }
}
```

Adding a listener and putting it all together is left as an exercise to <del>the reader</del> you.